# vb.net wpf datagrid - how to immediate save an updated row

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I have a DataGridthat is bound to an observable collection of clsActivity objects.

I want to find when a user modifies a row, then update the backend database.

I've tried using SelectionChanged and RowEditEnding events of the gridview but the RowEditEnding doesn't present the updated changes, just the original rows contents.

I've looked at using OnCollectionChanged of the observable collection but whilst this handles add/remove, it doesn't handle changes.  Also looked at using INotifyPropertyChanged but this looks like I'd have to monitor every property in every row and its a big DataGrid.

Is there a simple way of detecting and capturing changes in a row?

Is there an alternative (free) DataGrid control that does handle updates?

This was easy to do in winforms (and access years ago!)

My DataGrid

```
  <DataGrid x:Name="dataGridActivities" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,51,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.608,-2.219" Height="285" Width="411" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding activityStart, StringFormat=\{0:dd/MM/yyyy\}}" Header="Date" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding activityStartTime}" Header="Start Time"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding activityEndTime}" Header="End Time"/>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding notes}" Header="Notes" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
```

My dataGrid events code

```
'This picks up the original contents of the row fine.  I was hoping to store this and compare against the new contents in the next sub
Private Sub dataGridActivities_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles dataGridActivities.SelectionChanged
  Dim myActivity As New clsActivity
  myActivity = CType(dataGridActivities.SelectedItem, clsActivity)

  Debug.Print("SelectionChanged: " & CType(dataGridActivities.SelectedItem, clsActivity).ID)
  Debug.Print("Proj ID:" & myActivity.projectID & ", userID: " & myActivity.userID &
        ", notes:" & myActivity.notes)
End Sub

'This code just doesn't seem to pick up any changed data.
Private Sub dataGridActivities_RowEditEnding(sender As Object, e As DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs) Handles dataGridActivities.RowEditEnding
  Dim myActivity As New clsActivity
  myActivity = CType(dataGridActivities.SelectedItem, clsActivity)

  Debug.Print("RowEditEnding for row: " & CType(dataGridActivities.SelectedItem, clsActivity).ID)
  Debug.Print("Proj ID:" & myActivity.projectID & ", userID: " & myActivity.userID &
    ", notes:" & myActivity.notes)
'Was hoping to pick up the new contents of the row, then process them back to the database
End Sub
```

Comment: Just do it in the set of the property.

Comment: [This article](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2009/09/29/Inserting-Updating-and-Deleting-from-a-WPF-DataGrid.aspx) says to check the `EditAction` of the `DataGridRowEditEndingEventArgs` for `Commit`. Then you should have your updates.

Comment: @Crowcoder - I think the Important remark section in this article says it doesn't pick up changes.  Just checked anyway, and the e.Row.DataContext still shows the data before any changes.

Comment: @Paparazzi - sorry what do you mean?

Comment: @user3844416, that is if a Template is in use, which it is not given the xaml shown. Also, clearly the event is hit because you say old data is observed there.

Comment: I ran the code using Dim newDetails As New clsActivity
    newDetails = CType(e.Row.DataContext, clsActivity)    SelectionChanged: 29
    Proj ID:TC1-p2, userID: 12, notes:notes
    RowEditEnding for row: 29
    Proj ID:TC1-p2, userID: 12, notes:notes
    DataContext Proj ID:TC1-p2, userID: 12, notes:notes

Comment: Sorry formatting pants.  The output above shows the details of the row taken from the Selection changed event and the RowEditEnding Event.  For the last event I grabbed the grids selected item and the e.row.datacontext.

Comment: @user3844416, you have lost me. It should be a simple matter to try as shown in the article, the worst that can happen is that it still won't work. If you implement INotifyPropertyChanged you only need to do it on the class that is in the ItemsSource for the grid. Then you can add this to the binding which may also help: `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`

Comment: Look up property get set.

Comment: @Crowcoder - sorry.  I did try to use the e.row.DataContext and it doesn't show changes. As for INotifyPropertyChanged I'd need to do it on every column shown in the gridView (6), then hook up handlers for each row.  Then if the updateSourceTrigger is set to PropertyChanged it will call the update code every time a cell is changed.

Comment: Every column yes, every row, no. Make the collection IObservable.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Crowcoder.  Having to use INotifyPropertyChanged seems to be a lot of coding for what was a simple thing to do previously.  I think I need to replace this question and ask for a working example.  Many thanks again.